# Keep the file extension while zipping a file

Tags: filenames, zip

I want to zip a file called filename.txt

This is quite easily done with:

```
zip filename filename.txt
```

This will create a zipped file called `filename.zip`

However I want to keep the file extension in the file name.

As in create `filename.txt.zip`

Is this possible?

Comment: `zip filename.txt.zip filename.txt`... where is the problem ?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please don't forget to click the checkmark to indicate so. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you could create a function that does this for you:

```
myzip() { zip "$1".zip "$1"; }
```

Then call `myzip filename.txt` and you'll end up with `filename.txt.zip`